# WP MU - if I change a subsite domain, I can't use permalinks other than default

Tags: subdomain, permalinks, wordpress

I have a WP MU deploy. I'm using many subsites, all with the same base domain and diferent directories:

www.prueba.com/ar (for Argentina)

www.prueba.com/uy (for Uruguay)

www.prueba.com/cl (for Chile)

I want to set up a diferent subdomain for Brazil as:

www.prova.com (for Brazil)

Since Brazil's language is Portuguese and Spanish "prueba" = Portuguese "prova"

It's working, the only problem is it doesn't work with the permalink configuration called Post name "http://www.prueba.com/ar/sample-post/" (more friendly) BUT only with the Default configuration "http://www.prova.com//?p=123"

I can't figure out how to make it work with the special Portuguese domain AND post name permalinks.

Any advice?

Thanks guys,

Sandra Vega

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [Domain Mapping plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) for Wordpress. I have never used it but looks like a solution for your problem.

Comment: Thank you jakobhans but this plugin seems to resolve the problem I have already solved, (pointing one subdomain to another domain) but nothing to do with permalinks... :(

Answer (score 0):

I had to use "http://www.prova.com/br" and then it worked. Not the prettiest solution but acceptable